# OpenGL lighting coordinate system

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, lighting, coordinate-systems

So according to many sources I've read, most lighting should be done in eye-space (which is camera space).
The book that I'm reading also claims to be using lighting in eye-space, and I took its examples into my application as well.
In my application, the only thing that I pass to the fragment shader which is related to the camera is the camera position, and it's a model-space coordinate.
The fragment shader also uses a normal matrix which I pass in as a uniform, and its only use is to transform local-space normal vectors to model-space normal vectors.

So why is my lighting implementation considered to be used in eye-space although I never passed a model transformation matrix multiplied by a camera matrix? Can anyone shed some light on this subject? I might be missing something here.

Comment: The normal matrix transforms normals from object-space to eye-space. It's basically the inverse transpose (for proper scaling) of the top-left 3x3 part of your ModelView matrix. It serves the same purpose as the ModelView matrix, only it does not perform translation.

Comment: So you claim that my code, which is `prog.SetUniform("NormalMatrix", glm::transpose(glm::inverse(glm::mat3(ModelMatrix))));` should actually be `prog.SetUniform("NormalMatrix", glm::transpose(glm::inverse(glm::mat3(CameraMatrix * ModelMatrix))));`? The current code (without the camera matrix) works just fine.

Comment: No, I don't really know what *your* code should be. I am explaining what the normal matrix is in terms of the traditional OpenGL pipeline. I think when most books talk of which coordinate space lighting is done in, they are referring to the traditional fixed-function lighting design. In shaders you can do lighting in any coordinate space you want as long as all your vectors are in that space.

Comment: Where's the logic in calculating the lighting in eye space? the light should be always relative to the world. A sun is a "model" in world space and so is a lamp.

Comment: Well, consider fixed-function OpenGL, the model and view matrices are not separate. You transform straight from object-space to eye-space completely skipping over world-space.

Comment: Almost all lighting techniques will work in any coordinate system, as long as everything is in the same system.

Comment: So is it true that the normal matrix in my code transforms normals into model space and not eye space? Excuse me but I'm still trying to grasp this. Also, is it okay (and efficient) to compute lighting in both spaces? Like a scene with static light sources (that are computed in model space) and dynamic light sources (like a character holding a flashlight, computed in eye space).

Comment: @IsaacWoods: that is not true in general. Typically, lighting is _not_ done in clip space for example, as the perspective transform will distort the angles and distances.

Comment: So there's no difference between eye space lighting and model space lighting, apart from the actual matrices that I pass to the fragment shader and multiply my lighting calculation vectors with? Is it just about convention?

Comment: @Pilpel Without being pedantic, it will work in every system. Obviously, it would not work in clip space, but it would work, for example, in either eye space or world space, as long as the object, the light etc. were all in the same coord-system.